# One letter sub names. When is it a bad idea?

Tags: perl

I had a problem with calling a sub named with just one letter similar to the tests below. And I wasn't able to find some logic to which letters are allowed and not here. Is there any? I see why `sub m` is a bad idea as it conflicts with `m(regex)`, equivalent of `/regex/`. But why the others?

Of the tests below subs a, D, E, F are ok. The rest becomes `syntax error` according to perl v5.26 and v5.30 (the only two versions I checked)

```
perl -le'sub a{3*pop} print "a: ",a(7)-a(5)'              #prints 6
perl -le'sub b{3*pop} print "b: ",b(7)-b(5)'              #syntax error
perl -le'sub c{3*pop} print "c: ",c(7)-c(5)'              #syntax error
perl -le'sub d{3*pop} print "d: ",d(7)-d(5)'              #syntax error
perl -le'sub e{3*pop} print "e: ",e(7)-e(5)'              #syntax error
perl -le'sub f{3*pop} print "f: ",f(7)-f(5)'              #syntax error
perl -le'sub A{3*pop} print "A: ",A(7)-A(5)'              #syntax error
perl -le'sub B{3*pop} print "B: ",B(7)-B(5)'              #syntax error
perl -le'sub C{3*pop} print "C: ",C(7)-C(5)'              #syntax error
perl -le'sub D{3*pop} print "D: ",D(7)-D(5)'              #prints 6
perl -le'sub E{3*pop} print "E: ",E(7)-E(5)'              #prints 6
perl -le'sub F{3*pop} print "F: ",F(7)-F(5)'              #prints 6
perl -le'sub b{3*pop} print "&b: ",b(7)-&b(5)'            #prints 6
perl -le'sub b{3*pop} print " b: ",b(7)- b(5)'            #prints 6
perl -le'sub m{3*pop} print "m: ",m(7)-m(5)'            #prints 0
```

Answer (score 6):

Bad idea? Always, pretty much.

What is the problem in this specific case? [File test operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X). When you write `b(7)-b(5)`, Perl doesn't see a `-` binary operator and then a function call `b(5)`, it sees the file test operator `-b`, and then it throws a syntax error because it doesn't make sense to find a file test operator (or any kind of a term) immediately after a function call. There are 27 different letters (some uppercase and some lowercase) used by file test operators.

If you had written `b(7) - b(5)` then you wouldn't have gotten a syntax error, because `-b` wouldn't be found in your code... but that doesn't make single-letter names a great idea anyhow.

Comment: I see, thanks. I'm aware of file test ops, but somehow they didn't occur to me. Perl could perhaps have backtracked upon the syntax error here and tried looking for sub call instead (but too much of that would make the compiler slower perhaps, which we don't want either).

Comment: Also, q, m, s, y indicate the start of a single-quoted or regex literal